# Restrict Access for FLASK Application deployed to AWS ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to restrict access to view my Flask Webpage to only specified AWS users. Say I am doing a project for school, I follow the [Aws Tutorial for deploying flask app](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html), however once the app is published. Anyone can consume and post to the flask restful service.

I want to do the following

- Lock it down so only logged specific IAM users can view and run the rest service.

I am aware and tried using SSH to lockdown the in/out bound traffic to a specific IP. however I want to only lock it down to specific IAM groups for now. so say when someone tries to go to my application, amazon redirects for them login.

the site is the following, I want to restrict access to only specific roles or groups
http://XXXX-XXXX.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) in front of your app using IAM Authorization: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/

To configure the API Gateway to use IAM authorization from the console, go to the resources and click on your method. Then click on the Method Request and choose `AWS_IAM` in the Authorization dropdown: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a shot and post back tonight

Comment: I gave it a shot, and reviewed all the links you sent me. I was able to create a few custom policies using the suggested JSON examples and modifying them to suite my needs, but still having trouble locking down the site.

Comment: @dfresh22 I updated the answer with the method to add IAM authorization to your API Gateway